# Ext,apply and arrays

Tags: extjs

I'd like to merge two items arrays into one. I use for this the Exp.apply method. But the result contains only items from the second array.

Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/L3HHY/

The expected result should be

```
{ items:[{ name:'xxx' }, { name2:'yyy'}]})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function:

```
var items = [{name: 'a'}];

items.push({name: 'b'}); //  items = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]
```

Or [`Ext.Array.merge()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-merge):

```
items = Ext.Array.merge([{name: 'a'}], [{name: 'b'}])
```

Comment: Heh this is simple and works well, but I'm looking for a convenient way to handle more complex objects. The object could have more arrays and also some properties.